# existing tool to parse android xml files

Tags: android, xml-parsing

Are there existing standard tools to parse xml files in Android projects? By xml files, I mean AndroidManifest.xml and those GUI description xml files.

Comment: The Android Eclipse IDE displays these files as editable name/value pairs (instead of raw XML).  Would that work for you?

Comment: @paulsm4 As for reading/editing the files, I prefer using a plain text editor. But that's not I'm asking. I want to know whether there are tools to parse the files programmatically, and, better yet, to map them into (Java) objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no clean, separate library to do this, but implementing your own one is not complicated. The only tricky part is to model the difference between Android versions.